# Error importing numpy - ImportError: No module named mtrand

Tags: python

I have compiled and installed `numpy-1.11.2` from source as follows:
    python setup.py install

When I try to import it from Python, it gives me following error :

```
python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Mar 14 2016, 14:17:09)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/__init__.py", line 163, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from mtrand import *
ImportError: No module named mtrand
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Maybe this problem <https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7959

Answer (score -1):

Python can't find your numpy installation, maybe you can try with apt-get install python-numpy?

Comment: Please try to improve this answer with better formatting it, and perhaps a better explanation.